# Why is money used in transactions when it is dominated as a store of value?

Tags: money

In [Lectures on Macroeconomics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262022834) by O.Blanchard and S.Fisher (1993) stated that (the emphasize is mine):

> Building a model that formally explains why money is used in transactions
>   when it is dominated as a store of value has proved to be a difficult task.
>   **Consequently, most of the research has taken a shortcut and started with
>   the assumption that money must be used in some transactions; this 
>   constraint is known as the Clower, or cash-in-advance, constraint.**

But [Macroeconomics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429240024) by G.Mankiw (2012) mentions neither this difficulty nor  Clower constraint.

So has this difficult task been solved and the model that formally explains why money is used in transactions when it is dominated as a store of value has been created?